# Reduce \vspace between minipage{} environment

Tags: spacing, captions, subfloats, journal-publishing

How can I control the vspace between minipage{}, the following is a MWE demonstrating the extra white space between two minipage environments.

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{main:a}\includegraphics[scale=.35]{3_c.pdf}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{main:b}\includegraphics[scale=.35]{3_d.pdf}}
\end{minipage}\par\hspace{.005\linewidth} 
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{main:c}\includegraphics[scale=.5]{fig3cd.eps}}
\caption{\SI{500}{\nano\metre} pitch and 1:1 width ratio feature imaging: (a) Confocal microscopy image vertical lines, (b) SIM image of vertical lines; (c)  Line plot of (a) (blue) and (b) (red)}
\label{fig:3}
\end{figure}
```

[image: 1]

Alternatively the following MWE provides exactly what I want, except I do not know how to include subfigure captions such as (a) (b) and (c) to the following MWE subfigures.

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{3_c.pdf}
\hspace{.005\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{3_d.pdf}
\\[.5\baselineskip]
% \includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}
% \hspace{.005\linewidth} 
% \includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-b}
% \\[.5\baselineskip]
\includegraphics[width=8.4cm]{fig3cd.eps}
\caption{\SI{500}{\nano\metre} pitch and 1:1 width ratio feature imaging: (a) Confocal microscopy image vertical lines, (b) SIM image of vertical lines; (c)  Line plot of (a) (blue) and (b) (red)}
\label{fig:3}
\end{figure}
```

[image: 2]

As you can see, the white clearance between the figures is more compact than the first one, since I can control it. How can I achieve this in the first MWE OR how can I include subfigure captions in the 2nd MWE.

Comment: `\par\hspace{.005\linewidth}` what is the intention of the `\hspace` there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is normally no space:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{main:a}\rule{4cm}{4cm}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{main:b}\rule{4cm}{4cm}}
\end{minipage}\par
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{main:c}\rule{4cm}{4cm}}
\caption{blblb}
\label{fig:3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Probably the space is from some white border in your graphics. It is easy to reduce it by using some negative \vspace:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{subfig,color}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{main:a}\rule{4cm}{4cm}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{main:b}\rule{4cm}{4cm}}
\end{minipage}\par\vspace{-3\baselineskip}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{main:c}\textcolor{yellow}{\rule{4cm}{4cm}}}
\caption{blblb}
\label{fig:3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for finding out it is the WHITE PADDING around the picture and not vspace itself.